# Create a program in php which will open the downloaded file in new tab

Tags: php, file, browser, tabs

I'm new to php and i have to develop a program which will download file and open that file in new tab.

I have formulated code which works fine in terms of download.

**MY PROBLEM IS HOW TO OPEN THIS FILE IN NEW TAB ?**

**CODE :-**

```
Html code:-
<div class='data' onclick='download(\""+v.name+"\",\""+v.url+"\");'>

Jquery code:
function download(name,url){
                //alert('in');
                document.location = "download.php?filename="+name+"&url="+url;

            }   


php call
<?php
/******* Use to download the documents ********************/
    $file = $_REQUEST['filename'];
    $file_url = $_REQUEST['url'];
    $fileext =  strtolower(substr(strrchr($file,'.'),1));
    if($fileext == 'zip')
    {
        $contenttype = "application/force-download";
    }
    else if($fileext == 'pdf')
    {
        $contenttype = "application/pdf";
    }
    else
    {
        $contenttype = "text/plain" ;
    }
    $uri    = 'bbpsadmin/'.$file_url;
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header("Content-Type: " . $contenttype);
    //header("Content-Type: application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file) . "\";");

    readfile($uri);
    exit();
?>
```

Comment: Does file open in new tab or download in new tab ?

Comment: You can't do that with PHP but you can open the link in a new browser window by adding target="_blank" to your a tag, then browsers usually will use a new tab.

Comment: it opens in same tab i want to open it in new tab

Comment: i want to open that file in new tab..can you help me out please.

Comment: PHP is a *server side* language, it doesn't directly do things in the *client side* browser.  Try `target="_blank"` as @SaquibLari said.

Comment: Thanks but i have two buttons download and edit on download document gets downloaded successfully but on edit click it should open that document in new tab.

Answer (score 2):

This redirects the current tab/window:

```
document.location = "download.php?filename="+name+"&url="+url;
```

Whereas *this* opens a *new* tab/window:

```
window.open("download.php?filename="+name+"&url="+url);
```

Simply use `window.open()` when you want to open a new tab/window.  (Note: Whether what is opened is a tab vs. a window is a user or browser preference.)

Additionally, if you want the browser to [attempt to] open the file directly, then remove this header from the response:

```
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"" . basename($file) . "\";");
```

That header explicitly tells the browser that the response is a *file to be saved* rather than content to be displayed.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has nothing to do with that, all you can do with php is just setting the ["Content-Disposition"](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/Content-Disposition) header to inform the browser to whither open the resource in-line the browser or as an attachment to download. However this has nothing to do with your problem.

Changing the document `href` or using `window.open` approach will not open in new **tab** . if you really want it to be opened in tab and not in another window. you may need to change your div to an `<a>` element and use the target '_blank' for it

change this

```
div class='data' onclick='download(\""+v.name+"\",\""+v.url+"\");'>
```

Into this

```
<!-- I copied your onclick HTML code as it is  -->
<a id="download" target="_blank" href="" class='data' onclick='download(\""+v.name+"\",\""+v.url+"\");'>link</a>
```

and this

```
function download(name,url){
    //alert('in');
    document.location = "download.php?filename="+name+"&url="+url;
}
```

Into this

```
function download(name,url)
{
    var link = document.getElementById("download");
    link.href = "download.php?filename="+name+"&url="+url;
}
```